# Angular Call retries were exceeded exception while ng build

Tags: angular, typescript

My Angular 10 project is getting bigger, and at some point I've started to get an error while trying to build with `ng build --prod`. When I try to build, I am getting an error at the point of `Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...` and it says:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
See "...\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**ErrorLog:**

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (...\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (...\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:285:12)
```

I've noticed that if I comment out around 1k lines of my code at any of my components and try to build, it works. But when I re-open it and build again, then it gives the same error. I need to use differential loading, so I can't close it.

Node.js version: `v14.21.2`

Angular version: `~10.2.0`

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**What I've tried so far?**

- Increased the memory for the build process up to 12 GB - **failed**
- Added `"sideEffects": false` to my `package.json` - **failed**
- Deleted and reinstalled `node_modules` - **failed**
- Setting `"target": "es5"` in `tsconfig.json` - **success** (But this disables the differential loading)

Any ideas?